# Flask Python, trying to return list or dict to Ajax call

Tags: python, ajax, flask

Within a Flask app, I have the following ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "{{ url_for( 'bookings.get_customer' ) }}",
            type: "POST",
            data: nameArray,
            success: function( resp ){
                console.log( resp )
            }
        })
```

As you can see, I am passing an array against which I will search my mongo database, which will either return or not return a customer.

So, the python def that is responsible for handling this ajax call is:

```
@bookings.route( '/get_customer', methods=[ 'POST' ] )
def get_customer():
    name = {}
    for key, value in request.form.items():
     name[ key ] = value

    customer_obj = customer_class.Customer()
    results = customer_obj.search_customer( name )

    return results
```

For argument's sake, lets say the customer_obj call returns the following list:

```
[{'customer': {
               u'first_name': u'Dave', 
               u'tel': u'0121212121458', 
               u'country': u'UK',     
               u'address2': u'Townington', 
               u'address3': u'Cityville', 
               u'email': u'dave@smith.com', 
               u'postcode': u'A10 5BC', 
               u'address1': u'10 High Street', 
               u'second_name': u'Smith'
             }, 
 'customer_id': u'DaveSmithA10 5BCCat_Vegas1346244086'
}]
```

When I try to return this to the ajax call as

```
return results
```

I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1361, in
full_dispatch_request
response = self.make_response(rv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1450, in make_response
rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 711, in
force_type
response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 818, in
run_wsgi_app
app_iter = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Flask doesn't expect that you will return `list` object from your view function. Try `jsonify` it before:

```
from flask import jsonify

@bookings.route( '/get_customer', methods=[ 'POST' ] )
def get_customer():
    name = {}
    for key, value in request.form.items():
        name[ key ] = value

    customer_obj = customer_class.Customer()
    results = customer_obj.search_customer( name )

    return jsonify(customers=results)
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have been experimenting with sending dicts and lists to see if it made any difference. I have updated my question to make consistent, I got lost in the detail :). I will try your suggestion now.

Comment: You are a scholar and a gent, it works. I had to return a dict as opposed to a list - return jsonify( **results[0]), which isn't exactly what I want, but I can easily get a workaround for that. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

josonify works..but if you intend to just pass an array without the 'results' key, you can use json library from python. The following conversion works for me..

```
 import json

 @app.route('/test/json')
 def test_json():
 list = [
        {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
        {'a': 5, 'b': 10}
       ]
 return json.dumps(list)
```

Comment: One problem with this approach is that Flask will send the wrong add the `Content-Type` header. It will be set to `text/html; charset=utf-8`, rather than the semantically correct `application/json`

Answer (score 6):

You need to do

```
return jsonify(result=your_result)
```

Also check [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/) which could be really helpful.