# AJAX/JSON in server-side: pass all arguments to a Python dictionary (Flask)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I have a jQuery AJAX call in my Javascript that sends a lot of information to the server:
(Javascript)

```
    $.ajax({
        datatype: "json",
        url: SCRIPT_ROOT + '/email',
        data: $.extend({}, dict_list[0], dict_list[1]),
        success: (function(){console.log('E-mail success.')}),
        error: (function(){console.log('E-mail failure.')})
    })
```

Right now I'm just putting all the dictionary keys into a list and creating the dictionary like that:
(Python)

```
def testemail():
    """
    pre = ['red', 'blu', 'red_t', 'blu_t', 'red_p', 'blu_p', 'n_r', 'tou', 'mo', 'comm']
    post = [''] * len(prestats)
    for i in range(0, len(prestats)):
        post[i] = request.args.get(pre[i], '', type = str)
```

Is there a way, in my Flask Python server-side code, to automatically parse all that data into a dictionary? Basically I want something to take all the arguments that the $.ajax created and recreate a dictionary in Python.

Comment: Checkout the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193013/flask-python-trying-to-return-list-or-dict-to-ajax-call

Answer (score 2):

Could you be looking for request.json?